# PHP Class Scope issues

Tags: php, class

Below is a very basic example of the trouble I am having.

Now why must I use **$session = new Session();** in the **database.class.php** file when in my system the files are included in a way that it would be visible already.

In other words I cannot call $session = new Session(); outside of any other classes, to make it work in other classes I have to call create a new objectof the session class in every class I want to use it in, how can I avoid this and make it work without doing that?

```
// Session.class.php
class Session{

    public function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
    }

    public function set($name, $value)
    {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

...

```
// Database.class.php
class Database{

    public static function mysql_query_2($query)
    {
        if ($session->get('user_role') == 10){
            $_SESSION['queries']++;
        }
        return mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `$session = new Session();` in the code supplied anywhere. It might help us understand your problem.

Comment: @MitMaro sorry, the class is be started elsewhere in the script, I am wanting to only start it 1 time though and this way it is now requeires me to start it in every class file that uses a class from another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, one solution to your problem is to use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

```
final class Singleton {

    protected static $_instance;

    // Singleton can't be constructed or cloned
    protected function __construct(){ }  
    protected function __clone() { }

    // Create an instance if necessary and return an instance.
    public static function getInstance(){
      if( self::$_instance === NULL ) {
        session_start();
        self::$_instance = new self();
      }
      return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function set($name, $value){
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

In `index.php` you would have:

```
$session = Session::getInstance();
$session->get();
```

Then in your Database class you would have:

```
// Database.class.php
class Database{

    public static function mysql_query_2($query)
    {
        if (Session::getInstance()->get('user_role') == 10){
                $_SESSION['queries']++;
        }
        return mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

You would only ever create one instance of the Session class (which is what I think your looking for). Then when you need the Session class somewhere else (ie your Database class) you just call `Session::getInstance()` again. There is only one instance of Session ever created and you can use it globally across your script.

Comment: thanks for the code, this is probably the only solution but I will ask anyways, is it possible to call something like $session = new $session(); in for instance an index.php file and then be able to use it's methods in other classes or any other file that is included into the index file without basicly creating a new instance in every file?

Comment: I updated my answer but it doesn't really answer your question here. You could use the $GLOBALS [ http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php ] but a Singleton is much better.

Comment: I understand the singleton thing now but I still have the same errors, basicly I get errors if I do not initaite the class on every physical page that I need to use it so my problem is somewhat the opposite of a singleton, instead of needing the class to start 1 time I need to start it in every single file I include into a page that needs to use the methods from the class.  Hope I am making sense, it is driving me nuts trying to find out why I have to initiate it on every file.  If there is an index.php and a test1.php, test2.php, test3.php all 3 included into the index.php file, to avoid an

Comment: error, I must initiate a new object/call to the class in all the files to be able to use the $session->get($var) function in all these files, any ideas why it is requiring this?  It will say "Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object" if I use your code or even my code and the only way to make it work is to use something like $session = new Session(); in every file

Comment: for simplicity I will accept this and I have started a more specific question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463459/how-can-i-initiate-a-php-class-and-use-it-in-several-files if you care to see, thanks for your help so far =)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, your Session class should be a singleton - the reason is that multiple calls to session_start() will get you nothing but problems (session id gets regenerated)

So...

```
/**
 * Session singleton class
 */
class Session
{
    // prevents object instanciation ($obj = new Session())
    protected function __construct() {
        session_start();
    }

    // prevents object cloning
    protected function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if ($instance == null)
            $instance = new Session();
        return $instance;
    }

    // rest of the code
}
```

To use it you simply call:

```
$sess = Session::getInstance();
$sess->doSomething();
```

or simply

```
Session::getInstance()->doSomething();
```

Anywhere you need to use the session class.

Update:
 - I see you probably don't grasp the concept of singletons yet, so here's a proper [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) 8)

Comment: You beat me to it and you provided an example. +1

Comment: You have some errors in your singleton though, you are not returning the instance.

Comment: yep, that's fixed - coffee time i guess 8)

Comment: getInstance() needs to be a static function

Comment: thanks, I will add this in and for my question, I am trying to start the new object 1 time in the header part of my script but then in class files that are included, it is requiring me to start a new object everytime, like a scope issue, do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @jasondavis: Could you provide more code in your question. A singleton should fix your problem, unless we are still mis understanding it.

Comment: I will update the answer with a better explanation, but you don't instantiate singleton objects - there can be only one, and you just get it's instance.