# How to initiate a class and use it inside of multiple functions of a class

Tags: php, oop, class

I have some third party classes and I want to use it inside of different function of my new class.

Below is some structure of my own class:

```
<?php
$curl = new curl();

class stats
{
    public function foo1()
        {
            $foo1 = $curl->getPage($domain);
            // more stuffs
        }

    public function foo2()
        {
            $foo2 = $curl->getPage($domain);
            // more stuffs
        }
}
?>
```

but it's not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I initiate a PHP class and use it in several files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463459/how-can-i-initiate-a-php-class-and-use-it-in-several-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to really grasp some of the workings of OOP. Please refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php for more information.

If you want to use the `curl` variable inside your class, you should have defined it either as a property of that class or inside the methods of your class. A property will most likely suit your needs:

```
class stats
{
    private $_curl;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_curl = new curl();
    }

    public function foo1()
    {
        $foo1 = $this->_curl->getPage($domain);
        // more stuffs
    }

    public function foo2()
    {
        $foo2 = $this->_curl->getPage($domain);
        // more stuffs
    }
}
```

Comment: of course this is a way todo it, but leads to strictly binds in your classes. look into dependency injection.

Comment: I had tried this before but now I noticed that I was missing a part of it. Thanks.